# Javascript onkeyup function not working

Tags: javascript, onkeyup

Don't know whats exactly going on, but it's definitely killing my time for nothing. Here's my javascript function :

```
<script type="text/javascript"  >

function loadSponsorName() {
    var sp_id = document.getElementById('sponsor_id').value;
    var murl = 'load_sponsor.php?sp_id='+sp_id+'';

    var a=new Ajax(murl,{
        method:"post",
        onComplete: function(response){
        $('sponsorName').setHTML(response); 
        }
    }).request();
}
</script>
```

and inside a form this are my inputs

```
<tr>
    <td width="33%" height="20">
        <label id="namemsg" for="name">Sponsor ID:</label>
    </td>                          
    <td width="67%">
        <input type="text" name="sponsor_id" id="sponsor_id" size="40" value="" class="inputbox required" maxlength="50" onkeyup="loadSponsorName();" /> *
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td height="20">
        <label id="namemsg" for="name">Sponsor Name:</label>
    </td>                          
    <td><div id="sponsorName">
        <input type="text" name="sponsor_name" id="sponsor_name" size="40" value="" class="inputbox required" maxlength="50" /> *
    </div></td>
</tr>
```

It seems the onkeyup event is not even calling the function.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: if you write onkeyup="alert(1)" - it works?

Comment: it works for me - http://jsfiddle.net/x5t3b/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onkeyup is working try this javascript code to see how works;

```
function loadSponsorName() {
       alert(document.getElementById('sponsor_id').value);
}
```

I think there is a problem with;

```
 var a=new Ajax(murl,{
            method:"post",
            onComplete: function(response){
            $('sponsorName').setHTML(response); 
            }
        }).request();
```

Where is Ajax class? Did you import it from an other lib?

Comment: Thanks. That's right. But can you tell what library I can use for the code to work? I've a project that have this code and works fine. But when I imported to my project, it doesn't... I cant find any, but I think I'm missing the library you are referring...

Comment: Maybe these three lib meet your needs; http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/request and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/prototype/prototype_ajax_request.htm   or you must find Ajax class from your previous project

Comment: Hey :) Thats the perfect answer! I was missing the library and thats mootools.js. THANKS A LOTT!

Answer (score 0):

Ajax call in the handler + "handler not working aaaaaarghhhhh hellpppp" = usually means a not working Ajax call.

I am not sure what library you are using for your Ajax call, but try to add something like an onError callback function there where you are adding onComplete. I bet that will be called because there is a problem with the Ajax call.

Comment: I'm using <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: "I am not sure what library you are using for your Ajax call" - Is there any library required for this type of call? please let me know.